# Calling postgres function with multiple params

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

This is my sql function in postgresql:

```
FUNCTION test(year integer)
  RETURNS SETOF json AS
$BODY$
    SELECT  ARRAY_TO_JSON(ARRAY_AGG(T))
    FROM table t
    WHERE year = $1;
$BODY$
```

This works quite good. But now I want specify more parameters and 
I'd like to get a return with the condition if parameters are set. For example following function call:

```
test(year := 2014, location := 'Belo Horizonte')
```

How should the function look like and where to set conditions? Here is my (wrong) suggestion:

```
FUNCTION test(year integer, location text)
      RETURNS SETOF json AS
    $BODY$
        SELECT  ARRAY_TO_JSON(ARRAY_AGG(T))
        FROM table t
        IF $1 IS SET THEN
        WHERE year = $1
        ELSIF $2 THEN
        UNION
        WHERE location = $2
        END IF;
    $BODY$
```

A further challenge is a return of the function for this statements:

```
test(year := 1584)
-- should return all entries with year 1584

test(location := 'Cambridge')
-- should return all entries with location Cambridge

test(year := 1584, location := 'Cambridge')
-- should return all entries with year 2014 AND location Belo Horizonte
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may try to do something like that, adding default values, and working with OR clauses

```
FUNCTION test(year integer DEFAULT -1, location text DEFAULT 'noLocation')
      RETURNS SETOF json AS
    $BODY$
      SELECT  ARRAY_TO_JSON(ARRAY_AGG(T))
        FROM table t
        WHERE ($1 = -1 OR  year = $1)
        AND   ($2 = 'noLocation' OR  location = $2);
    $BODY$
```

Comment: Unfortunately this way do not solve the fact: If params are set then the query **must** consider the conditions. Another example: `SELECT test('Berlin')` would search for all entries with year = -1 (as parameter is not set and defaults to -1) and location = 'Berlin'. This is not the same like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE location = 'Berlin'`

Comment: @kOssi I may be wrong, but I think you didn't understand the solution. `SELECT test('Berlin')` would generate, for the year part `where (-1 =-1 or year = -1)` => same as "take every year". And for the location part : `and ('Berlin' = 'noLocation' or location = 'Berlin') => same as just `location = 'Berlin'`

Comment: ok, now I got it :-) There is still no real solution. If I proceed the query the database ends up in an infinite lookup. And aborting the query process crashes the database.